# How to check connection of cassandra with pentaho data integrator

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, cassandra, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I'm trying to load data from Oracle table to Cassandra table by using Pentaho Data Integration 5.1(Community Edition). But I'm not getting whether connection has been established between oracle and cassandra. I'm using Cassandra 2.2.3 and Oracle 11gR2.
I've added following jars in lib folder of data-integration
--cassandra-thrift-1.0.0
--apache-cassandra-cql-1.0.0
--libthrift-0.6.jar
--guava-r08.jar
--cassandra_driver.jar
Please anyone can help me to figure out how to check whether connection has been established in Pentaho.

Comment: please use cassandra 1.2.X , it won't work with any higher version of cassandra. example : 2.0.X or 3.0.X .
it is one open bug on pentaho site itshelf. you can google a bit and you will able to find that open bug link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some ways to debug if a connection is established to a database, I don't know if all of them are valid for cassandra, but I'll add a especial one for that.

> **1) The test button**

By simply clicking the test button on the connection edit screen.

[image: connection screen]

> **2) Logs with high details may help**

Another way to test is running you transformation with a [high detail log](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Pan+User+Documentation):

```
sh pan.sh -file=my_cassandra_transformation.ktr -level=Rowlevel
```

> **3) The input preview**

For cassandra, in especific, I would try just to create a simple read operation using Cassandra Input step and clicking in the 'preview' button.
[image: the preview button]

> **4) The controlled output test**

Or maybe you can try with a simplier transformation first, to make sure it's running fine. Eg.
[image: a simple transformation to test output]

Comment: Thanks for the solution I'll try these solutions MrMauric ioLeite

Comment: I've tried 4th solution by using Cassandra output component but now I'm getting following error: InvalidRequestException (why:Undefined name column_aliases in selection clause)

Comment: hummm seems to be a new error. That's good, it indicates progress at least. =)

take a look at this link, they seem to have had a similar problem and found a solution: http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?153531-why-Undefined-name-default_read_consistency-in-selection-clause

Comment: Thank you the link was helpful

Comment: as per my knowledge pentaho supports till 1.2.8 version as from cassandra 2.0.1 onwards cassandra have changed the metadata structure and pentaho has still not implemented that.
@MrMauricioLeite correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes that's true pentaho provides support only upto 2.0 version. I've tried with cassandra version 2.0.14 and connection created and data transferred from oracle table to cassandra.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance.