# Pentaho Cassandra input : Column family does not exist in keyspace

Tags: cassandra, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I am trying to set up an input step from Cassandra in Pentaho Spoon UI. But when I try to show schema or run the task I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: The column family local does not seem to exist in the keyspace system
at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.cassandrainput.CassandraInputDialog$10.widgetSelected(CassandraInputDialog.java:486)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.cassandrainput.CassandraInputDialog.open(CassandraInputDialog.java:632)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonStepsDelegate.editStep(SpoonStepsDelegate.java:136)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.editStep(Spoon.java:7835)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.editStep(TransGraph.java:2749)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.editStep(TransGraph.java:1998)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.mouseDown(TransGraph.java:809)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1221)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7044)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:8304)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:580)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:134)
```

I can access the table in the keyspace with CQLSH and DevCenter. I have also tried other keyspaces and tables only to get the same error.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated as I can't seem to find any previous answers to this issue here or in other forums.

Comment: Can you please share the screen-shot of your cassandra-input step details.
i want to check what and all you have specified.
you might be missed to enable: use CQLSH ..

Comment: I have actually spoken to people in Pentaho and the problem seems to be supported versions of cassandra. But thanks for taking a look I will post a response to my own question for the benefit of others who run into the same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer my own question. Having spoken to a few people in Pentaho. It is simply support for the version of cassandra that is lacking. I am using PDI spoon version 4.4.0 which apparently will only provide support for cassandra up to 2.0. In Cassandra 2.1  or higher there was a change to meta structure that hasn't yet been added to PDI.

Comment: Up to 2.0? or 1.2.8?
because when i tried it was not supporting from 2.0 onwards.

Comment: The pentaho doc's are crazy hard to dig through but the Pentaho people claimed 2.0, I have yet to test and will update when I have. But I also just found this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34635084/how-to-check-connection-of-cassandra-with-pentaho-data-integrator see comment by user Aniket "I've tried with cassandra version 2.0.14 "